# Trying to scrape table and keep getting empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some baseball related data and keep getting an empty list. I'm somewhat new to scraping and hoping someone can help.  Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/statss.aspx?playerid=2520&position=P'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

playerData = soup.find_all('tr', {"id":"SeasonStats1_dgSeason11_ctl00"})

print(playerData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `rows` have a different `id` than the parent table.

You can access them like this:

```
playerData = soup.find('table', {"id":"SeasonStats1_dgSeason11_ctl00"}).find_all('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

SeasonStats1_dgSeason11_ctl00 doesn't exist in your data. You need to wildcard it with lamda or regex

```
playerData = soup.find_all('tr',{"id": lambda L: L and L.startswith('SeasonStats1_dgSeason11_ctl00')})

print(playerData)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no row with the id *"SeasonStats1_dgSeason11_ctl00"*

But you could get the whole table with **'table'** instead of the row 'tr'

```
playerData = soup.find_all('table', {"id":"SeasonStats1_dgSeason11_ctl00"})
```